# Date Range functionality for Datebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datebox

I am using [Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) widget and want to limit the dates from which the user can choose. 
eg. Only dates between 2013-Jan-02 and 2013-Jan-25 should be enabled, rest disabled.

How do I provide these values **programatically** ? Passing it in JSON is not working for me.

```
$('#dateInput').datebox({"mode": "calbox", 'min':"2013-01-02", 'max':"2013-01-25"});
```

Please let me know the syntax to pass the date range parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether it is possible in Datebox widget. But if you pick Jquery UI datepicker, it has this option.

Have a look at this if you are interested

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: I want it in Datebox box widget. They support the functionality via HTML5 attributes min and max. But, I want to know how I can do the same via Javascript